# Developing a group, representation and algebra ( a first very simple likely false conjecture )

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I recently began trying to understand groups (one specific group) and algebras. In my reading, it struck me that I could potentially construct an abstract group and speculate about its representation.  What I came up with is this.

My first conjecture: There exists a group given by the quartet $(s,p,m, n)$ and a group law

$$(s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u)=(\frac{2}{3}sq, pr,m+(1-t)(s+1+n), nu)$$

where $s,p,m,n,q,r,t$ and $u$ are in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and the group admits at least one unitary representation.

I have *now checked some things and I want to believe nothing will go wrong. I am just adding and multiplying.

I want to first check that this is a group, so I suppose

*associativity

*identity

*inverse

As per Wikipedia's [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) of a group.
I then went further to just guess that a unitary representation exists.  Now that I have humiliated myself by thinking out loud on here, I am off to go hide but before I do, is this how it is done?

I want to call this guess and check?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138108/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-njokom-developing-a-group-representation-and-al).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity on the right is

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}, 1, 1, 1\right).$$

However,

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}, 1, 1, 1\right)\cdot(q,r,t,u)=\left(q, r,1+(1-t)\left(\frac{3}{2}+1+1\right), u\right),$$

which is not $(q,r,t,u)$.

Thus it is not a group.

Comment: So the left and right identities might be different.  So it seems for right now it could be a groupoid.  Let me see if there is an easy fix to the law to make the left and right identities the same.

Comment: I have answered the question as asked, @KevinNjokom. 
Please remember to accept it. If you wish to ask something else, then please start a new post.

Comment: yes, I am about to accept it

Comment: If I choose $m,t,s,n$ so that $m+(1-t)(s+n+1)=0$, which I can obviously do, then the product doesn't even lie in the set.

Comment: You can pick t to be 1, but I don't know if you can pick m to be 0 because it is not included in the set

Comment: Oh. You can  -m = (1-t)(s+n+1)

Comment: Maybe restricting the domain more could fix this, and still keeping the problematic  $ m + (1-t)(s+n+1)$ term

Comment: If we can restrict the domain so that the product remains in the set (closure?), can we attempt to draw one of those diagrams I see(commutative diagrams?) a  with right and left identity different

Comment: @DavidA.Craven  I have now created a follow-up post here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497581/restricting-the-domain-of-an-almost-group-a-commutative-diagram

Comment: @Shaun please also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497581/restricting-the-domain-of-an-almost-group-a-commutative-diagram