# Restricting the domain of an almost group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a quartet $(s,p,m, n)$ and a law

$$(s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u)=(\frac{2}{3}sq, pr,m+(1-t)(s+1+n), nu)$$

where $s,p,m,n,q,r,t$ and $u$ are in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

How can the domain be restricted so that we have closure? When we do attain closure, what is this structure?

I have tried just restricting to the  $\mathbb{R^+}$ and then reducing the domain bit by bit. Certainly, the first obvious thing was to remove 0 and then look at other quartets that might result in zero to see if there was a pattern.

Comment: You have asked too many questions in one post. Also, you need to provide context with each question, such as what you have tried and what your background is.

Comment: I have tried  just restricting to the  $\mathbb{R^+}$ and then reducing the domain bit by bit

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly, with details.

Comment: On background, I have some physics education but I don't want to embarrass the physics community so I am keeping that secret for now.

Comment: (Not everyone checks the comments for context.)

Comment: That's better, but you still need focus. Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Ok, in this post I will focus on the question of restricting the domain.

Comment: The problem seems to be the (1-t) term. as t increases  m(1-t)(s+1+n) becomes negative, so one can not remove $\mathbb{R^-}$

Comment: @Shaun ok, the (s+1+n) part is problematic.   s and n can be chosen such that  (s+1+n ) = 0 if we allow picking from $\mathbb{R^-}$ too.  If I change  (1-t) to (1+t)  to have   (1+t)(s+1+n) and then change the domain to $\mathbb{R^+} \setminus \{0\}$ then it should work I think.

Comment: @Shaun I take it back we need (1-t) to have an identity. So  (1-t)(s+1+n) stays. Perhaps restricting the domain further from $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: ok, so the  $(s+1+n)$ is the problem because, over the domain, it is always possible to pick s and n such that one gets 0.  I see two ways forward. Adding a condition that $n \neq -1 -s $ in addition to having a domain of reals excluding 0, or modifying the rule slightly to $$(s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u)=(\frac{2}{3}sq, pr,m+(1-t)(-st+1), nu)$$  over $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: Ok, so it seems that if I modify the law to $$(s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u)=(\frac{2}{3}sq, pr,m+(1-t), nu)$$, then the right identity is (3/2,1,1,1) and the left identity is  (3/2,1,-1,1)

Comment: I want to guess that for the inverses we should have (s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u) = (3/2,1,1,1)      and                                                         
(s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u) = (3/2,1,-1,1)

Comment: for right and left inverses

Comment: The domain will just be all the reals except 0

Comment: I think the problem with  (1-t)(s+1+n) was that it creates more than one identity element if (1-t) was 0 or if (s+1+n) was 0

Comment: @Shaun , please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498118/proving-a-group-like-object-always-has-a-unique-right-inverse-and-a-unique-left