# Proving a group like object always has a unique right inverse, and a unique left inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, groupoids

Given a quartet $(s,p,m, n)$ and a law

$$(s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u)=(\frac{2}{3}sq, pr,m+(1-t), nu)$$

where $s,p,m,n,q,r,t$ and $u$ are in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

The left and right identities have been found to be different which is ok. I believe these to be  $(3/2,1,1,1)$ for the right identity and $(3/2,1,-1,1)$ for the left identity. Please confirm this to be true.

How does one prove that every element obeying this law has an inverse or perhaps even a unique inverse (perhaps on the left and on the right)?

I want to reason that we start with a declaration (theorem?) that

$$(s,p,m,n)(q,r,t,u) = (3/2,1,1,1)$$

An  example:

$$(s,p,m,n )(1,2,3,4) =(3/2,1,1,1)$$

Then $(s,p,m,n) =(9/4,1/2,3,1/4)$

$$(s,p,m,n)(q,r,t,u) = (3/2,1,-1,1)$$

$$(9/4,1/2,3,1/4)(q,r,t,u) = (3/2,1,-1,1)$$

then $(q,r,t,u) = (1,2,5,4)$

Please check if these are even true. From checking it definitely looks like for every element there is a unique left and right inverse.  What is a good way of proving this?

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: This is not closed under the operation. If $m=1$ and $t=2$, then the third component of the result is $0$; e.g., $(1,1,1,1)(1,1,2,1) = (\frac{2}{3},1,0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $(3/2, 1, -1,1)$ is *not* a left identity, since

$$(3/2, 1, -1, 1)\cdot(q,r,t,u)=(q, r, \color{red}{-t}, u).$$

Comment: This is true.  I want to guess that if we change (1-t) to (1+t) we can have a left and right identity.

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498140/how-to-prove-that-a-unique-inverse-exists-for-every-element-of-this-group-like-s