# How to prove that a unique inverse exists for every element of this group like structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, groupoids

Given a quartet $(s,p,m, n)$ and a law

$$(s,p,m,n).(q,r,t,u)=\left(\frac{2}{3}sq, pr,m+(1+t), nu\right)$$

where $s,p,m,n,q,r,t$ and $u$ are in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

The right and left identities seem to be the same and are $(\frac{3}{2},1,-1,1)$ for the left identity and $(\frac{3}{2},1,-1,1)$ also for the right identity.  How can we prove that a unique left and right inverse exists for every element?

Comment: Indeed, the right and left identities will be the same, as the formula for their multiplaction is symmetric over its arguments, since normal addition and multiplication are both commutative,  and there is also a unique identity, since all the component equations have unique solutions since we left out 0. To show thar the inverses are unique, I think it sufices to show it component wise, i.e. define new multiplications returning only the first element of resultant quartet, and then prove that each of these results in a unique inverse, and that the combination of them is a complete inverse

Comment: Your set is not closed under the  operation. If $m=n=-\frac{1}{2}$, then the third component of the result is $0$, but you require all entries to be nonzero. E.g., $(1,1,-\frac{1}{2},1)(1,1,-\frac{1}{2},1) = (\frac{2}{3},1,0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that versed in group theory, but I can't see why closure would be a requirement for the left and right inverses to exist, they are not claiming that this structure does form a group, only that it is "group like"

Comment: @Carlyle: When talking about left and right inverses, we are talking about a binary operation. By definition, a binary operation on a set $A$ is a function $A\times A\to A$. What we have here is a function, not an operation, and the notion of "left identity" and "right identity" are  not applicable to general functions.

Comment: The third coordinates $m$ and $t$ should indeed be allowed to take the value $0$ (and when that is the case, this is indeed a real group). Note that the only candidate inverse to $(\frac32,1,-2,1)$ is $(\frac32,1,0,1)$, for example. (The map $(q,r,t,u) \mapsto (\frac23q,r,t+1,u)$ is a group isomorphism to $\Bbb R^*\times \Bbb R^*\times \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^*$.)

Comment: Ok so if I modify the domain to include 0 this should be a group. Can someone edit the question to include 0 in the domain, please?

Comment: If you include $0$ in the domain then it is not a group either, because $(0,0,0,0)(1,1,1,1) = (0,0,0,0)(0,0,1,0)$.

Comment: Really, it looks like you are just flailing hoping to come up with the magic formula that will somehow yield a group, with no rhyme or reason. If your formulas come from nowhere, you will end up nowhere, which is exactly where you are after much writing and accomplishing nothing.

Comment: I see. This is true

Comment: What are the easiest rules to observe to fix this to make it a group without mutating the law and domain too much?

Comment: @GregMartin what I am seeing here is that you can define the domain for each value?  Can you please edit the question as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not an operation, it's just a function. Taking $\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, the domain is $(\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}^*)^2$ and the image is $\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^*$ (note the third coordinate). Because we do not have an operation, the terminology of "left inverse" and "right inverse" is not really appropriate.

You can avoid this problem by taking tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ in which $a,b,d\in\mathbb{R}^*$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (so you allow the **third** coordinate to be $0$, but keep the first, second, and fourth nonzero).

If you do that, then you really have three different, independent operations: two on $\mathbb{R}^*$, one on $\mathbb{R}$, then put together with a direct product.

The first operation on $\mathbb{R}^*$ given by $a\cdot b = ab$, which is well-known to give a group;  this is what you do in the second and fourth coordinates. The identity is $1$, the inverse of $a$ is $\frac{1}{a}$.

The second operation on $\mathbb{R}^*$ is $a\cdot b = \frac{2}{3}ab$. This is also a commutative group operation on $\mathbb{R}^*$: the identity is $\frac{3}{2}$; it is associative, since
$$\begin{align*}
(a\cdot b)\cdot c &= \frac{2}{3}(a\cdot b)c = \frac{4}{9}abc\\
a\cdot(b\cdot c) &= \frac{2}{3}a(b\cdot  c) = \frac{4}{9}abc.
\end{align*}$$
The inverse of $a$ is the $b$ such that $\frac{2}{3}ab=\frac{3}{2}$, that is, $b=\frac{9}{4a}$, which makes sense because $a\neq 0$.

Finally, the third operation at play occurs in the third coordinate, where we have a map $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, given by $a\cdot b = a+b+1$. This is also a group: commutative, associative as $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a+b+c+2 = a\cdot (b\cdot c)$. The identity is $-1$, as $a\cdot -1 = a-1+1=a$; the inverse of $a$ is the unique $b$ such that $a+b+1=-1$, that is $b=-a-2$.

So what we have is three groups, $G_1$, $G_2$, and $G_3$, given as follows:

1. $G_1$ is the group with underlying set  $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and operation $a\cdot b = \frac{2}{3}ab$. Identity element is $\frac{3}{2}$, inverse of $a$ is $\frac{9}{4a}$.
2. $G_2$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero reals. The identity is $1$, the inverse of $a$ is $\frac{1}{a}$.
3. $G_3$ is the group with underlying set $\mathbb{R}$ and operation $a\cdot b = a+b+1$. The identity element is $-1$, the inverse of $a$ is $-a-2$.

Your group is the group $G_1\times G_2\times G_3\times G_2$. It is commutative, since each of the factor groups are commutative. The identity element is $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_2)= (\frac{3}{2},1,-1,1)$; the inverse of $(s,p,m,n)$ is $(\frac{9}{4s},\frac{1}{p},-m-2,\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Apologies again @Arturo, you seem much more knowledgeable about the subject, so I'm asking not because I think you're wrong, but simply because I would like to learn, why is it that left and right inverses are not entirely appropriate for something which is not an operation? Is it because the "identity" isn't really an identity because the the result of the multiplication by this identity yields something which looks the same, but lives in a different set, and is  therefore "different" by some interpretation?

Comment: Ah, I only saw your earlier comment now, Thanks

Comment: @Carlyle: essentially the same reason we don't say an arbitrary function of two variables is "commutative", namely the assumptions that go into the use of the technical term. E.g., we don't say the dot product on a real vector space is "commutative," but we do say it is "symmetric".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was wondering if it should be $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_2)$ ? also is the group $G_1 \times G_2 \times G_3 \times G_2$ instead since the second and fourth operations are the multiplicative group?

Comment: @KevinNjokom Yes, the fourth coordinate should be indexed with $2$, not $1$, throughout.