# What does the categorical/commutative diagram of this group look like?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory

A group has just been implemented. It is easy to work with. Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498140/how-to-prove-that-a-unique-inverse-exists-for-every-element-of-this-group-like-s/4498165#4498165) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498337/does-this-group-have-a-faithful-unitary-representation) before or after reading the summary below if you can.

Let $\mathbb{R^*} := \mathbb{R}$ \  $\{0\} $

Given the tuples (a,b,c,d) with a,b,d $\in \mathbb{R^*}$ and c $\in \mathbb{R}$.

$G_1 \times G_2 \times G_3 \times G_2$ with identity $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_2) = (\frac{3}{2}, 1,-1,1)$ and inverse $(s,p,m,n)$ is $(\frac{9}{4s},\frac{1}{p}, -m-2 ,\frac{1}{n})$ where :

$G_1$ is the group with underlying set $\mathbb{R^*}$ and operation $a \cdot b = \frac{2}{3} ab$

$G_2$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero reals

$G_3$ is the group with underlying set $\mathbb{R}$ and operation $a \cdot b = a + b + 1$

This group abstracted as $\mathbb{R^4 \times C_2^3}$ has been [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4498651/633012)  to have an 8-dimensional faithful unitary representation

I [found out](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/80-413-713/notes/chap04.pdf) that diagrams could be drawn to describe the group further. What does the commutative diagram of this group look like?

I have scribbled something on paper following page 66 of the reference above, but I have not done this before, so It would be good to know what it actually looks like.

Comment: What do you mean what do the diagrams look like? all the groups are defined by diagrams of the same shape, what changes are the definitions of the maps, and you already provided this information.

Comment: I did not know this. Ok so you mean there is a generic shape, but the identity, inverse and so forth are are unique from group to group, which then go on the diagram?

Comment: I meant to say the maps are unique

Comment: ok so basically I just need the same diagram, but then specify the definitions of the maps

Comment: Exactly. Your last comment is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "diagrams" defining the group is the same as for any group: there is the group operation $\mu: G\times G\to G$, the identity $\epsilon: \{\ast\}\to G$ and the inverse $\iota: G\to G$. Then there are various diagrams encoding the fact that the operation $\mu$ is associative, the identity $\epsilon$ is indeed an identity on the left and on the right, and the inverse map $\iota$ has the correct property. They are the exact same diagrams for every group.